# iPhone - View for UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am an absolute beginner in iPhone development(consider this while rplyng please), I have this Navigation based application in which there is view called FirstView.

In this I have a scrollview and imageview. I set Image of Image view on a button click. Then after the click I
have this code

```
imageView.image=image;
imageTitle.text=text;

scrollView.clipsToBounds=YES;

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:[self scrollView] cache:NO];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp animation was working fine if I set the animation view as imageView. But if I set it for scrollView (like above), the animation does not happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the scrollView variable properly connected to the displayed scroll-view?
E.g. set a breakpoint at that "scrollView.clipsToBounds=YES;", when reaching the breakpoint while executing, check the current value of the scrollView variable. It should display a non-NIL value.